# awk split and concatenate has extra space in one line of output

Tags: awk

The below `awk` produces the `current output` with all the lines `split`.  However the first line seems to have a space in it and I can not seem to figure out why.  Not sure if this is the best way but it produces output that is close to correct. Thank you :).

**awk**

```sh
awk '{split($6,a,":"); print $1":",$2,$3,a[1],a[2],a[6],a[7]} {split($7,a,":"); print $1":"$2,$3,a[1],a[2],a[6],a[7]} {split($8,a,":"); print $1":"$2,$3,a[1],a[2],a[6],a[7]} {split($9,a,":"); print $1":"$2,$3,a[1],a[2],a[6],a[7]} {split($10,a,":"); print $1":"$2,$3,a[1],a[2],a[6],a[7]}' input > parse
```

**input file** (tab delimited)

```
chr1    13408   C   1   =:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  A:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  C:1:2.00:28.00:2.00:0:1:0.00:0.02:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00 G:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  T:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00  N:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0:0.00:0.00:0.00:0:0.00:0.00:0.00
```

**current output (parse)**

```
chr1: 13408 C A 0 0 0 (has a space between `chr1:` and `13408`)
chr1:13408 C C 1 0 1
chr1:13408 C G 0 0 0
chr1:13408 C T 0 0 0
chr1:13408 C N 0 0 0
```

**desired output**

```
chr1:13408 C A 0 0 0 (has no space between `chr1:` and `13408`)
chr1:13408 C C 1 0 1
chr1:13408 C G 0 0 0
chr1:13408 C T 0 0 0
chr1:13408 C N 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even notice that... thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre telling awk to print a space with the first `,` in your first print statement. Change

```
print $1":",$2
```

to

```
print $1":"$2
```

like you already have in your second print statement so you don't get the `OFS` value (a space by default) printed between `:` and `$2`.